# SQL Server: retrieve rows which to not satisfy an event criteria at least once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to pull a data which gives a list of all children who were not seen during a month. Each row in the dataset represents one contact event. I have two programs - pulls all contacts events which satisfy the “contact met” criterion and one which brings back everything else which is all the contact events which did not meet the contact criterion. The list I need is all the children how did not meet the contact criterion at least once.

**Here is a dataset I start with:**

```
Child_Name  Unit    Contact_Date    Contact_Method  Contact_Result  Participant
Chiddick    P5J 5/17/2013           Face To Face    Contacted                 No
Chiddick    P5K 5/1/2013                 Phone            Contacted               No
Chiddick    P5K 5/2/2013                 Phone            Contacted               No
Chiddick    P5K 5/3/2013                Face To Face    Attempted                 No
Chiddick    P5K 5/6/2013                  Phone           Contacted               No
Chiddick    P5K 5/7/2013                Face To Face    Attempted                 No
Melgar  P5F 5/13/2013               Face To Face    Attempted                Yes
Melgar  P5F 5/13/2013                 Phone           Attempted              Yes
Melgar  P5F 5/15/2013             Face To Face  Attempted                Yes
Silva   P5G 5/8/2013              Face To Face  Attempted                 No
Silva   P5G 5/31/2013             Face To Face  Attempted                 No
Bennett     P5E 5/1/2013              No Contact    No Contact
Bennett     P5E 5/8/2013              Face To Face  Contacted               Yes
Bennett     P5E 5/17/2013           Face To Face    Contacted                 Yes
Abreu     P5G   5/14/2013           Face To Face              Contacted               Yes
Abreu      P5G  5/29/2013            Face To Face   Attempted                 Yes
```

This query is for Contact Events met:

```
SELECT
Child_Name,
Unit,
Contact_Date,
Contact_Method,
Contact_Result,
Participant
FROM [DimContacts_Child]
where Unit in('P5C','P4C','P5L','P5D','P5F','P5G','P5E','P5A','P5K','P5J')
and (Contact_Date>='2013-05-01' AND Contact_Date <='2013-05-31')
and **(Contact_Method ='Face To Face')AND (Contact_Result<>'Attempted')AND (Participant='Yes');**
```

Results:

```
Child_Name  Unit    Contact_Date    Contact_Method  Contact_Result  Participant
Bennett P5E 5/8/2013               Face To Face Contacted                 Yes
Bennett P5E 5/17/2013               Face To Face    Contacted                 Yes
Abreu   P5G 5/14/2013              Face To Face Contacted                 Yes
```

This query is Contact Events NOT met:

```
SELECT
Child_Name,
Unit,
Worker_Name
Contact_Date,
Contact_Method,
Contact_Result,
Participant
FROM DimContacts_Child]
where Unit in('P5C','P4C','P5L','P5D','P5F','P5G','P5E','P5A','P5K','P5J')
and (Contact_Date>='2013-05-01' AND Contact_Date <='2013-05-31')
and **not** **((Contact_Method='Face To Face')AND (Contact_Result<>'Attempted')AND (Participant='Yes'));**
```

Results:

```
Child_Name  Unit    Contact_Date    Contact_Method  Contact_Result  Participant
Chiddick    P5J 5/17/2013              Face To Face Contacted                 No
Chiddick    P5K 5/1/2013                  Phone           Contacted               No
Chiddick    P5K 5/2/2013                  Phone           Contacted               No
Chiddick    P5K 5/3/2013               Face To Face Attempted                 No
Chiddick    P5K 5/6/2013                   Phone              Contacted               No
Chiddick    P5K 5/7/2013               Face To Face Attempted                 No
Melgar  P5F 5/13/2013                Face To Face   Attempted                Yes
Melgar  P5F 5/13/2013                 Phone           Attempted              Yes
Melgar  P5F 5/15/2013              Face To Face Attempted                Yes
Silva   P5G 5/8/2013               Face To Face Attempted                 No
Silva   P5G 5/31/2013              Face To Face Attempted                 No
Bennett P5E 5/1/2013               No Contact   No Contact  
Abreu   P5G 5/29/2013              Face To Face Attempted                 Yes
```

If you notice Bennett and Abreu were the only children which satisfied the contact criterion for met at least once during the month. What I need is a list of the of the children which in all thier contact events did not satisfy the criterion at least once.

This is what I need:

```
Child_Name   Unit
Chiddick     P5J
Melgar   P5F
Silva    P5G
```

This three kids to not meet the requirement at least once. I can't figure out how to modify the query for just this. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `group by` and `having` clause:

```
SELECT Child_Name, Unit
FROM DimContacts_Child
where Unit in ('P5C','P4C','P5L','P5D','P5F','P5G','P5E','P5A','P5K','P5J') and
      (Contact_Date >= '2013-05-01' AND Contact_Date <='2013-05-31')
group by Child_Name, Unit
having sum(case when (Contact_Method='Face To Face') AND
                     (Contact_Result <> 'Attempted') AND
                     (Participant='Yes')
                then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The aggregation is counting the number of "valid" contacts in the month.  If there are any, then the sum is greater than 0.  If not, then then sum is 0, and the child is in the result set.

The only issue is the relationship between the child and unit.  As written, the query looks at a contact in each unit.  You might want to remove `unit` in the `group by`, to get results based only on each child (I included it because it is in your desired result set).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `EXCEPT`. I'm not going to copy all your code above, but something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Child_name, Unit FROM <THE QUERY WITH CRITERION NOT MET>
EXCEPT
SELECT Child_name, Unit FROM <THE QUERY WITH CRITERION MET>
```

The two queries should have the same amount of columns; that appears to be the case in your example.

In order for this to work, you should also only compare on the columns that shouldn't be the same.

Ie. in your case, the `SELECT` clause should probably only contain `Child_name` and `Unit`. The reason for this is that `EXCEPT` filters on identical rows in the two queries. So if you include `Child_Name`, `Unit` & `Contact_Date` in the first query, the rows will only be filtered away if the second query have the same dates for the same `Child_Name` and `Unit`, which isn't likely as I read your question.

Comment: @user2270911 Actually, you will need to reduce the columns a bit. I'll update my answer to reflect that.